# EF - cannot convert from System.Linq.IQueryable to System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need subtract the result of `contentCategories` from `allCategories` at the moment I use `.Except` method but I receive an error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong... many thanks

```
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsCategory>>' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsCategory>'
```

---

```
            int contentId = Int32.Parse(uxContentsListSelector.SelectedValue);
            var allCategories = from category in context.CmsCategories select category;
            var contentCategories = from content in context.CmsContents
                                          where content.ContentId == contentId
                                          select content.CmsCategories;
            var result = context.CmsCategories.Except(contentCategories);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an additional `from in` clause in order to get a flattened list.

```
var contentCategories = from content in context.CmsContents
                        from cat in content.CmsCategories
                        where content.ContentId == contentId
                        select cat;
```

I would then change your `Except` method to an `Any` method

```
var result = context.CmsCategories.Where(cat => !contentCategories.Any(c => c.CategoryId == cat.CategoryId));
```

Comment: That is not what he's askin for, and your solution does not address his problem. Check my answer for the correct approach.

Comment: Hi Aducci I really appreciate your help on this. your last line of code had fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the last select you're doing. Also you're code is highly reduntant. Let's take it by steps:

```
var allCategories = from category in context.CmsCategories select category;
```

You can rewrite the same in a more concise way:

```
var allCategories = context.CmsCategories;
```

Then this is wrong: you're selectin a query of collections instead of a single collection:

```
var contentCategories = from content in context.CmsContents
                                      where content.ContentId == contentId
                                      select content.CmsCategories;
```

The correct way to do that is:

```
var contentCategories = (from content in context.CmsContents
                                      where content.ContentId == contentId
                                      select content).First().CmsCategories;
```

Which is, again, redundant, and can be written in a better way:

```
var contentCategories = context.CmsContents.First(c => c.ContentId == contentId).CmsCategories;
```

The last statement is right.

Comment: hi, i receive this error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsCategory'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: As I told you before, you need to provide the code that is generating the error, otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks Matteo for your comment, I used your code and as before I still receive the same error, as I sad for sure I'm doing smt wrong myself as I'm a beginner. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: The message itself means that you're trying to use an instance of CmsCategory as a value for a constant, which is not allowed. Again, if you post the line of code that is throwing this exception, we can provide an accurate answer.

Comment: this is the code:             var allCategories = context.CmsCategories;
                var contentCategories = context.CmsContents.First(c => c.ContentId == contentId).CmsCategories;
                var result = context.CmsCategories.Except(contentCategories);

Comment: the problem I receive using the last line: var result = context.CmsCategories.Except(contentCategories);